# How many clients are connected to specified UDP port number in c#

Tags: c#

How can I count the number of clients connected to a UDP socket in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IPGlobalProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getudpipv4statistics) and one of these methods

```
IPGlobalProperties.GetUdpIPv4Statistics
```

> Provides User Datagram Protocol/Internet Protocol version 4 (UDP/IPv4)
>   statistical data for the local computer.

for ipv6 there is also another function

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a connectionless protocol, so there are no connections to count.
IPGlobalProperties.GetUdpIPv4Statistics only gives you the number of listerners on the system, which I don't think is what you are looking for.
It would be helpful if you specify what you are trying to do!